# How to join in MYSQL multiple tables with foreign key relationships including entries without corresponding entries

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Hi I have a central table of resources which are linked to categories and activities by foreign key tables.

So the tables are:
**resources** (r):
-id
-name
**resources_categories** (rc):
-resource_id  (=r.id above)
-category_id  (=c.id below)
**categories** (c):
-category_id  (=c.id above)
-category_name
and
**resources_activities** (ra):
-resource_id  (=r.id above)
-activity_id  (=a.id below)
**activity** (a):
-activity_id  (=a.id above)
-activity_name

I want to select items from resources even when there is no corresponding foreign key entry for category or activity assigned as there is a 1-to-many (or 1-to-none) relationship between resources and categories, and resources and activities.
*ie all resources with their cateogories and activities if they have them*

But don't seem to be able to do so, even after trying various joins and unions and trying using where is null or is not null or is <>'' etc

Here is a query that works but doesn't include all the resources:

```
SELECT `r`.`id` ,  `r`.`name`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `c`.`category_name`), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `a`.`activity_name`)  
FROM `resources` AS `r`   
RIGHT JOIN `resources_categories` AS `rc` ON `r`.`id` = `rc`.`resource_id`   
JOIN `categories` AS `c` ON `rc`.`category_id` = `c`.`id`   
RIGHT JOIN `resources_activities` AS `ra` ON `r`.`id` = `ra`.`resource_id`   
JOIN `activities` AS `a` ON `ra`.`activity_id` = `a`.`id`   
GROUP BY `r`.`id`
```

Here resource categories is a foreign key table that joins the resources with their categories and activities.
But this is not listing resource entries without a category or activity listing - how do I do that?

Comment: I should have said  'ie all resources with their categories and activities if they have them' - regardless of whether they have a category or activity but the answers seem to have it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Then you want a `left join` not a `right join`:

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.category_name), 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.activity_name)
FROM resources r LEFT JOIN
     resources_categories rc
     ON r.id = rc.resource_id LEFT JOIN
     categories c
     ON rc.category_id = c.id LEFT JOIN
     resources_activities ra
     ON r.id = ra.resource_id LEFT JOIN
     activities a
     ON ra.activity_id = a.id
GROUP BY r.id;
```

A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the *first* table when there is no match.  A `RIGHT JOIN` keeps all rows in the *second*.  Most people find it much easier to read queries that have chains of `LEFT JOIN`s rather than `RIGHT JOIN`s.  There is rarely any (good) reason for mixing the two different types of joins.

Comment: This seems to nearly have it. I seems to be a LEFT OUTER JOIN that I was looking for. Thank you so much for your extremely rapid response and clarifying my misunderstanding of which was the left and right! Though the LEFT JOIN seems to work too!

Comment: But how do you put this in terms of $query->select, and -> join please?

Answer (score 0):

resources AS r RIGHT JOIN resources_categories join selects all rows from the table on the right hand side, so from resource_categories table. So, instead of right joins use left ones in your query to return all resources regardless of corresponding records in the other tables